Riddle: Call me George
Call me George
Remove my first, and you'll get old cattle
Remove my second, and you'll start to be right
Remove my third, and you'll find yourself
Remove my last, and nothing is left

The knowledge tag wouldn't happen to apply here, would it? I have a possible solution in mind, but I believe it would warrant that tag.

@BlueHerring I think the tag would apply

Call me George

 Yuri - the Slavic form of the name George

Remove my first, and you'll get old cattle

 uri - plural of urus or aurochs, an ancestor of domestic cattle

Remove my second, and you'll start to be right

 ri - right

Remove my third, and you'll find yourself

 I

Remove my last, and nothing is left
